# Prove that no matter what integer k you choose, the number $7k+3$ will not be a perfect square.

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that no matter what integer k you choose, the number $7k+3$ will
>   not be a perfect square.

My thought when attempting this problem is to use a proof by contradiction, and suppose that there is some k where $7k = a^2 - 3$ but im unsure on how to prove it after this, maybe it has something to do with modulo which we just learned about briefly on Friday?

Comment: Compute the following numbers $(7n)^2$, $(7n\pm 1)^2$,  $(7n\pm 2)^2$,  $(7n\pm 3)^2$ modulo $7$ first. (Here, $n$ is an integer.) Or equivalently $0^2$, $(\pm1)^2$, $(\pm2)^2$, $(\pm 3)^2$ modulo $7$. Which values may occur?

Answer (score 2):

Any integer $n$ is of the form $7k+j$ for a unique integer $k$ and a unique $j \in \{ 0,1,\dots,6 \}$. This $k$ is the quotient when $n$ is divided by $7$, this $j$ is the remainder.

Now show that the remainder when $(7k+j)^2$ is divided by $7$ is the same as the remainder when $j^2$ is divided by $7$. So you reduce the problem to computing a few remainders.

Choosing to take $j \in \{ -3,-2,\dots,3 \}$ will also work, and will make the arithmetic a little bit easier to do by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Any square has remainder $0,1,2$ or $4$ when divided by $7$.

---

Since any integer modulo $7$ is equivalent to $0,1,2,3,4,5$ or $6$. Any square is equivalent to $0^2,1^2,2^2,3^2,4^2,5^2$ or $6^2$ modulo $7$.